# Skip folder if it does not exists using java

Tags: java

I have created a property file in java named prop.properties inside eclipse.

In prop.properties file, I have added below lines:-
users = user1,user2,user3

where user1 , user2 and user3 are folders.

I have created directory named TestDir which contains,
user1,user3 folders

Suppose if user2 folder is not present in TestDir, I have to skip that and consider the other folder.

I have used the below code,

```
int fileCount = directory.list().length;
File[] logFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (logFiles != null) {
                for (File f : logFiles) {
                System.out.println(f);
                }
}
```

But I am getting error. The error is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because the return value of "java.io.File.list()" is null
```

Can someone help with resolution

Comment: Read the docs.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#list()   "If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is getting the count when the directory list is null will fail on the first line. Add a test that sets `fileCount` to zero in that case. Like,

```
File[] logFiles = directory.listFiles();
int fileCount = (logFiles == null) ? 0 : logFiles.length;
for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) { // <-- this is safe
    File f = logFiles[i];
    System.out.println(f);
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this throw NullPointerException at `for (File f : logFiles) {` if the value of `logFiles` was null - or rather which JDK does this work on?

Comment: @DuncG Thanks. I meant to change it to a regular loop using `fileCount` and forgot. Fixed.